# Geometry library in C++

Tags: c++, geometry

I am looking for an easy to use and well documented geometry library in c++. I would like to use it in 3D perception that I am dealing with point clouds. Coordinate transformations, rotations and translations are my special concern now. Any suggestion?

Comment: On [softwarerecs.se]: [Geometry library for C++](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16702/60)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A very powerful library is [cgal](http://www.cgal.org/). Some of the functions in [opengl](http://www.opengl.org/) may also be of use.

Comment: Be careful with the licensing of cgal, if that's of concern. I had to pass on it when considering geometry libraries because of the commercial license requirement.

Comment: Some parts of cgal are released under LGPL and some under QPL, commercial license agreement is `In cases where the constraints of the Open Source license prevent you from using CGAL`. So far I haven't had problems with the licensing, but as with all libraries one has to pay attention to the license before deciding on the best alternative.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.geometrictools.com/ if you're looking for a less restrictive license. It may not do all that CGAL does, but it's very clean and rather complete looking with a Boost license.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Boost::Geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html)

It has some basic point definitions and coordinate systems as well as distance calculations. From there you can extend it as needed.

There's also some intersection routines and things to find convex hulls from clouds of points.

Comment: the wording 'basic point definitions' could be a bit misleading :) IMO there is little 'basic' about Boost Geometry's coordinate systems

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this site](http://clb.demon.fi/MathGeoLib/nightly/alternatives.html). It gives you a very good overview about existing geometry libraries, even with some pros and cons.

**Update:** 
And you may also have a look at the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org). It's quite a new library for working with point clouds, easy to understand and has plenty of good tutorials to get started with!

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

[PLIB: A Suite of Portable Game Libraries](http://plib.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Note: Just because it says "game" it doesnt mean you cant use it in anything other than developing games.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to render your geometries in a VGA screen, I strongly recommend you to use microsoft DirectX library which is the best one for graphics rendering. Otherwise, just go with Boost::Geometry library which would be enough for your purpose.